# Hibernate configuration and property files

Tags: spring, hibernate, jhipster

I generated my app using Jhispter. I'm trying to find configuration file for Hibernate and mappings file. Does anyone know how is this achieved in jhipster?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate configuration is done by Spring Boot application properties in `application*.yml` files in `src/main/resources/config` folder.

Mappings are done by JPA annotations (`@Entity`, `@Column`, ...) on entity classes in `domain` package.